# previous declaration of 'namespace reference { }'

Tags: c++, libxml2

I am getting compilation error when I compiling  my code with `libxml2`.

File `Reference.h` already exists in my code and being used by many other files:

```
Reference.h
namespace reference // BEGIN OF namespace reference
{

}
```

But I am getting error when I am compiling my code with `libxml2`:

```
libxml2/libxml/SAX.h:116: error: 'void reference(void*, const xmlChar*)' redeclared as different kind of symbol

libxml2/libxml/SAX.h
XMLPUBFUN void XMLCALL reference (void *ctx,
       const xmlChar *name);
```

Is there a way to resolve this error without modifying my file `Reference.h`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could wrap all the libxml2 usage in a set of files that doesn't use your `reference.h` header file.

Comment: This is essentially a bug in libxml2 which I [just fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/commit/1dafb427d9e61559fbe12e530537b8096e4c315c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, disable `SAX.h`. That's a deprecated interface, which doesn't bother to do any namespacing or use any standard prefix for its symbols. Instead, use `SAX2.h`, which (in addition to other improvements) prefixes everything with `xmlSAX2`.

To keep the deprecated stuff out of your libxml2, when you run `configure` make sure not to pass the `with_legacy` option.

Comment: If you're stuck with a system libxml2 library or want your code to be portable, you could also define `__XML_SAX_H__` before including the libxml2 headers.